# how to make server who receive file from android app?

Tags: php, android, mobile, web

I am android developer and zero at back end process. Whats stuff/tools require for making a server/website that receives files from android app. I listen somewhere that php code is required as backend on server side. Is is true?

hoping for detailed explanation. Sorry for my english.
Thanks.

Comment: Do you need to upload the file to server, or just send, store data to server?

Comment: yes, store to server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

need php file for coonecting with database.use phpmyadmin(xampp)
    tool for creating database.then create phpfile n post on server or  localhost. after that use url in android.like our php link is localhost:80/phpproj/trial.php
    and pass value to database using asyctask method.